# Must declare the scalar variable @empname

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Getting Error in Csharp :

```
string sq = "select EmpName,contactnumber,dob,Address from tbl_emp_details where empname = @empname";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sq, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", comboBox1.SelectedText);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sq, con);
// com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname",Name.SelectedText);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
Name.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Empname"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating the data adapter using the original *SQL* and not the *command* (which includes the parameter) that you create.

Change

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sq, con);
```

to

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: It now throws another error saying no value found at row 0, may be because i m looking for row number based on my condition where empname=@empname. How do i overcome this.

Comment: Check to see if the table is empty before trying to get a specific row. If you use an employee name that is not found you'll get an empty datatable.

Comment: The table has data, I think the problem is because i have mentioned rows[0], what do i replace it with

Comment: If the table has data, then there should be no error with `rows[0]`. What is the specific error message?

Comment: it says you have no row at position 0 -- exact error